# Question marked as duplicate is notified as a new comment for users already on the question

Tags: bug, duplicate-questions

I have no idea if this is expected behavior or not, and I have grown used to it, but it seems like there could be a better way to notify the user.

To clarify the situation:

Someone asks a question.
**User 1** opens the question to read it.
**User 2** marks it as a duplicate.
**User 1** sees a notification under the question saying someone posted a comment.

Upon the click on this notification, it disappears but nothing else changes on the page.
**User 1** has to reload the page to see that the question was marked as a duplicate.

Couldn't we just show the duplicate without needing to reload the page?

Comment: No, that's a bug. Some "reload" actions don't seem to properly reload the comments (and vote count). Cache seems to be too aggressive.

Answer (score 1):

This a common situation when a Gold badge owner is closing with the dup-hammer. By default, when you don't have a gold badge and you vote to close as duplicate a comment is added automatically saying "Possible duplicate of ..." and when the question get closed that comment disappear.

When it is done by a gold badge owner both actions are done at the same time: comment added (you get the notification), comment deleted, question closed.